# What is wrong with this code to calculate the Beta of a stock?

Tags: python, statistics, stock, quantitative-finance

I am calculating the beta of a stock based off of the SPY. However my calculations do not produce the same numbers as I see on Yahoo Finance and Zacks. The beta of a stock is the covariance divided by the variance. Below is the code and the output when I call `get_beta(['AAPL'])`

Code:

```
    def covariance(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        hist2_closes = hist2['Close'].to_list()
        length = len(hist2_closes)

        hist2_average = 0
        for day in hist2_closes:
            hist2_average += day
        hist2_average = hist2_average / length

        total = 0
        for i in range(len(SPY_hist)):
            total += ((SPY_closes[i] - SPY_average) * (hist2_closes[i] - hist2_average))

        return total / (length - 1)

    def variance(self, SPY_hist):

        SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        sum = 0
        for i in SPY_closes:
            dif = i - SPY_average
            sum += (dif ** 2)

        return (sum / (length-1))


    def beta(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        _covariance = self.covariance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist, hist2=hist2)

        _variance = self.variance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist)

        return (_covariance / _variance)

    def get_beta(self, securities):

        SPY_hist = yfinance.Ticker('SPY').history('1mo')
        betas = {}

        for security in securities:
            security_hist = yfinance.Ticker(security).history('1mo')
            b = self.beta(SPY_hist=SPY_hist, hist2=security_hist)
            betas[security] = b

        return betas
```

Output:

```
{'AAPL': 0.6610297779078679}
```

I tried both Apple and Tesla. Both times the beta produced was low. I looked over the code multiple times but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. However, I am almost sure that Apple's beta should be higher than the SPYs'. When I used a five year period and 1 month interval I was expecting a beta around 1.27 for Apple and 2.07 for Tesla but Apples' was .66 and Tesla's was 1.5.

**UPDATE**

I read on this [page](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/beta-everything-know-measuring-stock-170027831.html) that Yahoo calculates beta using this formula: `Beta = (Stock’s % daily change and Index’s % daily change) / (Index’s % daily change.)` . I implemented the percent change function and changed the code to take values from the percent change function that I will put below. My values are closer not but they are still off. Now Apple is 1.14 and Tesla is 2.5.

New Code

```
    def covariance(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        #SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        SPY_closes = SPY_hist
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        #hist2_closes = hist2['Close'].to_list()
        hist2_closes = hist2
        length = len(hist2_closes)

        hist2_average = 0
        for day in hist2_closes:
            hist2_average += day
        hist2_average = hist2_average / length

        total = 0
        for i in range(len(SPY_hist)):
            total += ((SPY_closes[i] - SPY_average) * (hist2_closes[i] - hist2_average))

        return total / (length - 1)

    def variance(self, SPY_hist):

        #SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        SPY_closes = SPY_hist
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        sum = 0
        for i in SPY_closes:
            dif = i - SPY_average
            sum += (dif ** 2)

        return (sum / (length-1))


    def beta(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        _covariance = self.covariance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist, hist2=hist2)

        _variance = self.variance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist)

        return (_covariance / _variance)

    def percent_change(self, hist):

        closes = hist['Close'].to_list()
        percent_change = []
        for i in range(len(closes)):
            if i != 0:
                percent_change.append(((closes[i-1] - closes[i]) / closes[i-1]) * 100)

        return percent_change

    def get_beta(self, securities):

        SPY_hist = yfinance.Ticker('SPY').history('1mo')
        SPY_pc = self.percent_change(hist=SPY_hist)
        betas = {}

        for security in securities:
            security_hist = yfinance.Ticker(security).history('1mo')
            security_pc = self.percent_change(hist=security_hist)
            b = self.beta(SPY_hist=SPY_pc, hist2=security_pc)
            betas[security] = b

        return betas
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that Yahoo Finance and Zack's use percent change to calculate Beta instead of alpha. In addition after making this change I had forgotten to change the period back to five years and the interval to one day. The values are now satisfactory. This is the final code:

```
    def covariance(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        #SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        SPY_closes = SPY_hist
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        #hist2_closes = hist2['Close'].to_list()
        hist2_closes = hist2
        length = len(hist2_closes)

        hist2_average = 0
        for day in hist2_closes:
            hist2_average += day
        hist2_average = hist2_average / length

        total = 0
        for i in range(len(SPY_hist)):
            total += ((SPY_closes[i] - SPY_average) * (hist2_closes[i] - hist2_average))

        return total / (length - 1)

    def variance(self, SPY_hist):

        #SPY_closes = SPY_hist['Close'].to_list()
        SPY_closes = SPY_hist
        length = len(SPY_closes)

        SPY_average = 0
        for p in SPY_closes:
            SPY_average += p
        SPY_average = SPY_average / length

        sum = 0
        for i in SPY_closes:
            dif = i - SPY_average
            sum += (dif ** 2)

        return (sum / (length-1))


    def beta(self, SPY_hist, hist2):

        _covariance = self.covariance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist, hist2=hist2)

        _variance = self.variance(SPY_hist=SPY_hist)

        return (_covariance / _variance)

    def percent_change(self, hist):

        closes = hist['Close'].to_list()
        percent_change = []
        for i in range(len(closes)):
            if i != 0:
                percent_change.append(((closes[i-1] - closes[i]) / closes[i-1]) * 100)

        return percent_change

    def get_beta(self, securities):

        SPY_hist = yfinance.Ticker('SPY').history(period='5y', interval='1mo')
        SPY_pc = self.percent_change(hist=SPY_hist)
        betas = {}

        for security in securities:
            security_hist = yfinance.Ticker(security).history(period='5y', interval='1mo')
            security_pc = self.percent_change(hist=security_hist)
            b = self.beta(SPY_hist=SPY_pc, hist2=security_pc)
            betas[security] = b

        return betas
```